# Some customers don't have the option to pay without having a PalPal account

Tags: paypal

I have customers who want to be able to pay via PayPal without needing to create an account.  This works for me (and most users I believe) - I get a "Pay with credit card or debit card" button as shown below.

[image]

However, one customer sent me this screenshot, with the same button stating "Create an account" instead.  I can't seem to find any explanation for this behaviour.  Does anyone know why? (Note: like me, all customers are in Australia)

[image]

Comment: What library/SDK/whatever are you using to generate that form?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better question for PayPal customer support?

Comment: Are they on a VPN?  Does it work the same from a Chrome incognito window (in a browser where you've *never* logged into Paypal, basically)?

Comment: @Luke I'm using the NVP API.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen PayPal customer support is the next option, but their first support option is to post a question here. See https://developer.paypal.com/developer/support

Comment: @DeanJ I cut down the screenshot. The customer is using IE, so I did my shot (against the live site) in IE too (which I've never used to log into PayPal).  I just did it in Chrome's incognito mode, and it works as I'd expect (I have the option to pay with a credit/debit card).  Unfortunately I'm a couple of layers away from the customer, so I don't know if they're using a VPN.

Comment: PayPal does not offer guest checkout to all buyers in all countries.  Depending on a number of variables involved, some users simply will not get that option.

Comment: @AndrewAngell The customer is in Australia (as am I), so I'd expect that to be fine. Was hoping to find out what other variables might be involved.